# Arduino - is it possible to do some scrolling text?

Tags: rgb, arduino-uno, led

is it possible to do some scrolling text?
[RGB led matrix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-LYYBJsu4Y)
[red led matrix only](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOuKnOG8atk)
can i use this WS2812 rgb led matrix instead of MAX7219 to build RGB scrolling text? because i want to build a project like multicolors of scrolling text just like in the video of MAX7219. but in the video of MAX7219 is red led only.

i also want to know what is the latest arduino uno R3 using the chip is ATmega16U2 or ATmega328
thanks

Comment: Which language are you talking about? These questions attract much better responses the more detail the question has.

Comment: im using this in arduino uno r3 to be able to build some rgb scrolling text just like in the video of MAX7219

Comment: Hi @KennyTan, did you find what you are looking for, on google, first. If yes, what are the answers?(e.g you need to put them on your question) Second, this is a Q&A"s website. You'll need to provide some modicum of code...:)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. You can use either solution for scrolling text.
2. The primary MCU of all Arduino Unos is the ATmega328P. The ATmega16U2 of the Uno R3 is used as a USB-UART bridge.